# Clearing a line from the Prolog terminal in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, prolog, keyboard-shortcuts

So I have Prolog in a terminal within VS Code, but sometimes it crashes and I restart it. Out of habit, I quickly press <kbd>↑</kbd> to get my last Prolog query, but because my history is not there anymore it only shows the very long line of my `.pl` file that I just loaded in. Is there a way to quickly remove this line without holding backspace for a few seconds?

I tried pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> but this doesn't work in the Prolog terminal.

Comment: If the Prolog is using readline in vim mode, then `Esc` followed by pressing `d` twice will clear the line, then press `a` (i.e. append) to get back to normal typing. This is what I use in swi-prolog. readline is configured in e.g. `/etc/inputrc` in Linux.

Comment: Simply pressing `Esc` did the trick! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> clears the line. Thanks @brebs for the comment leading to the solution.